# Forming query in Alfresco Full Text Search for JSON text file

Tags: json, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to query an exact match from a JSON text file using Alfresco Share's Full text search. For example, if the file has text in a JSON format as below, is it possible to query for an exact match for the fields, test, params2, valueb:2?

```
  {test: 
        {params1:
                 {valuea:1,
                  valueb:2}
        },
        {params2:
                 {valuea:3},
                 {valueb:2}
        },
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Alfresco ist not a JSON DB ([Anti-Pattern #4](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2014/06/26/3896)), the text is just indexed as full text.
You'll have to use properties (-> [Alfresco Content Model](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html)) to be able to query for your fields.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not a JSON DB. But going along the text route, how would I go about querying using regular expressions for my intended fields? In addition, when you talk about user properties, are you saying that I have to populate each field as part of my custom content model?

Comment: Going the text route is not an option here. You won't be able to hit the results you're expecting: http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2014/06/26/3896 #Anti-Pattern-4
Yes, you'd have to define every prop in your content model. There are use case where it makes sense just to store the content & basic(static) meta-data in Alfresco and use MongoDB or similar to store your JSON props